Use System.Text.Json converters with JsonTypeInfo for AOT
My .NET 8 application is AOT-compiled so it needs to use JsonTypeInfo and cannot use reflection-based serialisation. Now I also want to use the converter feature to store objects differently than in memory. I found that I can create a basic converter class and add it to my JsonSerializerOptions instance.
But there is no overload of the serialisation methods that accepts both JsonSerializerOptions (required for converter) and JsonTypeInfo (required for AOT).
Does that mean that converters are not compatible with AOT? What should I do? Copilot wasn't able to help me but at least recognised that no such desired method overload exists.

Can't you set JsonSerializerOptions.TypeInfoResolver to your JsonSerializerContext.Default instance?  According to How to use source generation in System.Text.Json: Use source-generation defaults you should be able to do that, what problem are you having?

Do be aware that there can be problems with native AOT when using JsonConverter factories that use Type.MakeGenericType() to create the actual JsonConverter<T>.  A [mcve] showing your actual problem would help clarify.

To use a runtime JsonConverter with a compile-time JsonSerializerContext, you can create JsonSerializerOptions initialized with the converter and context, then call JsonSerializerOptions.GetTypeInfo(Type) to get the JsonTypeInfo<T> you need to serialize your root model using the AOT APIs.
First create the following extension methods:
public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    public static string Serialize<TValue>(TValue value, IJsonTypeInfoResolver resolver, params JsonConverter [] converters)
    {
        var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
        {
            TypeInfoResolver = resolver,
        };
        foreach (var converter in converters)
            options.Converters.Add(converter);
        var jsonTypeInfo = (JsonTypeInfo<TValue>)options.GetTypeInfo(typeof(TValue));
        return JsonSerializer.Serialize(value, jsonTypeInfo);
    }

    public static TValue? Deserialize<TValue>(ReadOnlySpan<char> json, IJsonTypeInfoResolver resolver, params JsonConverter [] converters)
    {
        var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
        {
            TypeInfoResolver = resolver,
        };
        foreach (var converter in converters)
            options.Converters.Add(converter);
        var jsonTypeInfo = (JsonTypeInfo<TValue>)options.GetTypeInfo(typeof(TValue));
        return JsonSerializer.Deserialize(json, jsonTypeInfo);
    }
}

Now let's say your model and context look like, e.g.:
public record Model(Foo Foo);

public record Foo(string Value);

public class FooConverter : JsonConverter<Foo>
{
    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Foo value, JsonSerializerOptions options) => 
        writer.WriteStringValue(value?.Value);
    public override Foo? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) => 
        reader.GetString() is {} s ? new Foo(s) : null;
}

[JsonSerializable(typeof(Model))]
public partial class SourceGenerationContext : JsonSerializerContext
{
}

If you would like to serialize Model using FooConverter for its Foo value, you will be able to do so as follows:
var model = new Model(new("hello world"));

var json = JsonExtensions.Serialize(model, SourceGenerationContext.Default, new FooConverter());
var model2 = JsonExtensions.Deserialize<Model>(json, SourceGenerationContext.Default, new FooConverter());

// JSON is {"Foo":"hello world"} not {"Foo":{"Value":"hello world"}}

Incidentally, rather than calling options.GetTypeInfo(), you could simply pass your JsonSerializerOptions using the required context and converter directly into Serialize() and Deserialize() like so:
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    TypeInfoResolver = SourceGenerationContext.Default,
    Converters = { new FooConverter() },
};
var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(model, options);
var model2 = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Model>(json, options);

While this is documented to work in How to use source generation in System.Text.Json: Use source-generation defaults, I have found that doing so generates a bunch of IL3050 and IL2026 compiler warnings in .NET 8:
Program.cs(78,15): warning IL3050: Using member 'System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize<TValue>(TValue, JsonSerializerOptions)' which has 'RequiresDynamicCodeAttribute' can break functionality when AOT compiling. JSON serialization and deserialization might require types that cannot be statically analyzed and might need runtime code generation. Use System.Text.Json source generation for native AOT applications.
Program.cs(78,15): warning IL2026: Using member 'System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize<TValue>(TValue, JsonSerializerOptions)' which has 'RequiresUnreferencedCodeAttribute' can break functionality when trimming application code. JSON serialization and deserialization might require types that cannot be statically analyzed. Use the overload that takes a JsonTypeInfo or JsonSerializerContext, or make sure all of the required types are preserved. 

Despite that, the code works, and generates JSON without needing to use reflection. In this answer to Can't compile with Native AOT about JsonSerializer.Deserialize, tipa has confirmed (from MSFT) that these warnings are a false positive when TypeInfoResolver has been set to a JsonSerializerContext.  But since the warnings are annoying, I suggest using the extension methods above instead.
